# How do I visit archive-post.php?

Tags: archives

I have a simple file with the loop in it to get all posts called `archive-post.php`, but I'm not sure how I get to it in the URL?

`http://www.examples.com/post/` gives me a 404

How can I see the archive of all my posts (not custom post types)?

Comment: Try saving your permalinks again

Comment: Any specific reason why you would like to do this

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes, very simple one really: I have a Static Page as my homepage and I just want to find a link to the normal posts page (ie. what would normally be shown as the homepage). There's probably a really simple solution to this!

Comment: That makes more sense. The updated answer from @TomJNowell will then work for you :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't, `archive-post.php` doesn't exist, it's just `archive.php`, and on most sites the post archive is the root of the site, aka `/`. Depending on how you're viewing posts it'll use `home.php`, `front-page.php`, `index.php`, etc. You should refer to the [template hierarchy diagram](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg), but remember, the standard `post` post type is a special case, as are pages

Perhaps adding your own rewrite rules, or specifying `post_type=post` in the URL as a query variable, or toggling the `pre_get_post` filter that's adding your custom post types to the main query

If you've set a page as your homepage, there is an option directly next to that option that lets you set the posts page, which will give you what you want. ( as a sidenote, you don't need to set a page as your homepage to give it a custom design, that's what the `home.php` template is for )

For example, this is my own site:

[image]

Where posts is a page called posts at `/posts/`. Of note, it will not use a page template if I assign one to that page, it uses the archive/index templates instead

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I have a Page as my site "root", so that's why I'm looking for another way to view all posts.

Comment: Underneath the homepage option in settings is a posts page option, that's what that option is intended for

Comment: Incredibly counter-intuitive, but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use Page Template.
Add these line to the top of the file:

```
<?php
/**
*Template Name: Post Archive
*/
?>
```

Then you will create a new page, choose Post Archive for its page template box. That is, when you visit this page, you will get your posts archive.